# Theano missing nvcc compiler

Tags: environment-variables, ubuntu-14.04, gpu, theano

I install theano on ubuntu 14.04 using below commands  :

```
sudo apt-get install python3-numpy python3-scipy python3-dev python3-pip python3-nose g++ libopenblas-dev git

sudo pip install Theano
```

I have installed cuda7.5. If I run `ncvv --version`, I get below message :

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2015 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Aug_11_14:27:32_CDT_2015
Cuda compilation tools, release 7.5, V7.5.17
```

I cannot use theano gpu version. My command and error message is here :

```
$sudo THEANO_FLAGS=mode=FAST_RUN,device=gpu,floatX=float32 python test1.py

ERROR (theano.sandbox.cuda): nvcc compiler not found on $PATH. Check your nvcc installation and try again.

[Elemwise{exp,no_inplace}(<TensorType(float32, vector)>)]
Looping 1000 times took 2.507168 seconds
Result is [ 1.23178029  1.61879337  1.52278066 ...,  2.20771813  2.29967761
  1.62323284]
Used the cpu
```

Comment: Don't use sudo before command. Show results of command: "sudo which nvcc".

Comment: If I don't use, I get permission denied error. empty result. `$ sudo which nvcc
                       $`

Comment: When you use sude then your path env  dont see nvcc

Comment: ok, so you should change owner or permissions of file test1.py, and then run python script without sudo.

Comment: The owner of test1.py is not root. But I can't use theano without root mode.

Comment: Have you set the path for "cuda" in .theanorc?

Answer (score 1):

First, check and see whether there is a file named NVCC at '/usr/local/cuda/bin/'. If there is go on with the following commands and if not, I suppose you have to install CUDA toolkit, etc.

Only run the following commands:

```
$ export PATH="/usr/local/cuda/bin/:$PATH"
$ source .bashrc
```

You might have to restart too but it should work even if you do not restart.

Comment: export PATH="/usr/local/cuda/bin/:$PATH"  and then :
source .bashrc

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the folder of the cuda compiler to the PATH variable:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.5/bin/:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

then run `ldconfig`